# How to unblock pan and pinch events in a UIScrollViewDelegate?

Tags: ios, events, gestures, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a UIView which has a UIScrollView subview and is a UIScrollViewDelegate. Since I've implemented `viewForZoomingInScrollView` I stopped getting pan and pinch events for the UIView.

How can I get these events back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a delegate to your gesture recognizer that implements

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

`[yourviewname setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`

---

Edit:  I just re-read your question.  Are you saying that you can't pan and/or pinch?  Or are you saying that you aren't being notified when you pan and/or pinch?

Comment: My problem was that I wasn't notified when the user pinched or panned. Edwin Iskandar's suggestion fixed it.